# Laravel Join query with LIKE

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent

```
$toReturn['exams'] = exams_list::where('examAcYear',$this->panelInit->selectAcYear)
    ->join('classes', 'exams_list.examClasses', '=', 'classes.id')
    ->where('classes.classTeacher', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->data['users']->id.'%')
    ->select('classes.*','exams_list.exam_name')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Is this query correct? I have to join 2 tables `classes` and `exams_list`, but am not getting any values.

Comment: Are you able to provide the structure of the two tables you are trying to join? Can you also confirm whether you have models for your "classes" as well as for "exam_lists"?

Comment: Yeah,models with this name has been defined. In table, exams_list the field 'examClasses' the values are stored in array format like eg: ["1","2","3"] and in the other table classes.id is the primary key of the table 'classes'.

Answer (score 0):

**Explaination**

---

I think your problem lies in how your `join` clause is working.

If `classes.id` is of type `(int)` and `exam_list.examClasses` is of type `(array)` or `(json)`, then it is unlikely that you will get a successful join in the first place. You could test this by removing the where clause and seeing if you get any results.

**Solution**

---

I would suggest changing the eloquent relationship between your `classes` model and `exam_list` model to be either a many to many relationship with a pivot table or a simple one to many relationship.

You will need to decide for yourself which make the most sense for your project! I would highly recommend reading the documentation on eloquent relationships to get a better understanding of how they will help you in this scenario.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

**Example**

---

Below is an example of a Many to Many relationship you might use:

**Models/Classes.php**

```
/**
 * A class belongs to many exam lists
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function examLists()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Exam_list::class, 'classes_exam_lists');
}
```

**Models/Exam_list.php**

```
/**
 * A exam list has many classes
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function classes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Classes::class, 'classes_exam_lists');
}
```

**Migration**

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('classes_exam_lists', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('class_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('class_id')->references('id')->on('classes')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('exam_list_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('exam_list_id')->references('id')->on('exam_lists')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['class_id', 'exam_list_id']);
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('classes_exam_lists');
}
```

With these changes (and providing you have robust relationships between your models) you can then use eloquent to get the information you need by doing something like this:

```
$exam_list = Exam_list::where('examAcYear',$this->panelInit->selectAcYear);

$collection = $exam_list->classes()->where('classTeacher', $this->data['users']->id)->get();
```